# how to write extension method for paging in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pagination, extension-methods

i've define static class to enable paging :

```
public static class Pager
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> PageData<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int currentPage, int pageSize)
   {
       var sourceCopy = source.ToList();

       if (sourceCopy.Count() < pageSize)
       {
            return sourceCopy;
       }

       return sourceCopy.Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
   }
}
```

and i want in my controller to do like :

```
var pagedDataCourses = products.OrderBy(p => p.productName).PageData(currentPage, pageSize);
```

so where i can put that static class/method so i can get extension method for paging in all controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static IQueryable<T> Page<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int page, int pageSize)
{
   int skip = Math.Max(pageSize * (page - 1), 0);
   return query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);
}
```

You will have to put it in the same namespace as where you are using the extension. Or us the "using" at the top of your .cs files

Comment: `OrderBy` call has to be there in the supplied query. Otherwise `Skip/Take` won't work for relational LINQ providers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MVC contrib paging http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid